# evaluate if item in list has property that fulfills condition

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a simple task loop through a list and if one of the properties in the list contains a value it should evaluate to true. However for some reason the value always returns true and the list has count greater than 0.

```
var goodsIssuesSubmitted = _goodsissueRepository
    .Where(gi => gi.attributes.Status == "Submit")
    .ToList();

var submittedTr = goodsIssuesSubmitted
    .Select(gi => gi.relationships.data.Where(g => g.TransportId == _transportId))
    .ToList();

if (submittedTr != null && submittedTr.Count > 0)
{
    goodsIssueHasbeenSubmitted = true;
}
```

How can I make it so that the  `goodsIssueHasbeenSubmitted` evaluates to false if  no items are returned from the list based on the condition specified.

Comment: FYI, `submittedTr` will never be `null` after the `Select` and `ToList` calls, so you can simplify your `if` condition to: `if (submittedTr.Any())`

Comment: Also, do you have a question?

Comment: @RufusL yes The question is above , I edited it to make it more explicit

Comment: You can get rid of the `if` and do the assignment directly: `goodsIssueHasbeenSubmitted = submittedTr.Any();` But your code looks fine, which is why I asked what the question is. You said, *for some reason the value always returns true and the list has count greater than 0*, yet that's the exact code you wrote (if count > 0, set variable to true).

Comment: @RufusL the question was I would like the count to be 0 and therefore evaluate to false  if the conditions are not met.

Comment: Ok, now that I read the accepted answer I get what the problem was. Maybe I'm just tired, but I couldn't get that from what you posted. In fact, I was going to suggest combining the queries, but I figured you might be using `goodsIssuesSubmitted` elsewhere as a local repository base for other queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you project the `goodsIssuesSubmitted` collection to return the result of the `Where` condition what it does is for each item in `goodsIssuesSubmitted` it returns a collection of sub-items matching the nested condition of `g.TransportId == _transportId`.

Then in your if statement you only check the existence of items in the `submittedTr` collection and not what those items contain. Therefore, in the case of a non empty `goodsIssuesSubmitted` collection the second condition is just irrelevant and thus the observed behavior. To fix that change that second `Select` and `Where` to `Any`.

Also you can simplify the query as follows:

```
goodsIssueHasbeenSubmitted =_goodsissueRepository.Any(i => 
    i.attributes.Status == "Submit" && 
    i.relationships.data.Any(g => g.TransportId == _transportId)))
```